# Fixed keyboard inside a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, keyboard, fixed

Is there a way to include a keyboard inside of a view? 
I want it to be part of the view and not be dismissed as well.

Birdfeedapp does this in it's 'add account' modal view.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just add this code to your view.
This will show the keyboard:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [YOURTEXTVIEW becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: My problem is, I am creating the textField and adding it to a tableView during the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. So the textfield is not available at viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Either make a text field as the first responder and keep it the first responder or create your own keyboard.