# How to show the keyboard for a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, becomefirstresponder

I have a UIView where I want to receive keyboard input. I have tried:

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

But it doesn't work.

I could implement a 'dirty' workaround by having a hidden UITextField and forwarding the keystokes to my UIView - but how does my UIView receive the keyboard input directly?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103040/fixed-keyboard-inside-a-uiview this might fix your problem...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a view to become first responder and show the keyboard, it must adopt and implement the `UIKeyInput` protocol. It must also override the `canBecomeFirstResponder` method to return YES.

See [“Simple Text Input” in the *Text Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies/LowerLevelText-HandlingTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH15-SW13).

Answer (score 0):

Becoming a first responder will only show the keyboard if that object is meant for keyboard input like a text field. The idea of having a hidden text field is good but it also depends on what you need the keyboard input for, regarding your view. Getting the text form the hidden text field is trivial and that way the text or whatever you need there, can be used by your view.