# UIKeyboard not appearing when tapping on UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

[image: This is the Signup VC ,as Tapping pops the white space Not the KeyBoard][image: This is the login VC ,as Tapping pops the white space Not the KeyBoard]

I had been into a weird problem, As every other thing is working fine. All of sudden when I compile my application and got this problem, when I tapped on the `UITextField` white space is popping up, but the keyboard is not visible and I am not able to enter anything.

Comment: it would be great to see screenshot attached...

Comment: can u show the screen shot of the view

Comment: do check the post ,updated the screenshot

Comment: wow, have never seen anything similar...

Comment: what about other text fields? same result? Do you use some controls/custom classes for UITextField?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the keyboard for a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819707/how-to-show-the-keyboard-for-a-uiview)

Comment: @jww NOt duplicate of the mentioned question ,as i wrote in the question that everything is working fine ,all of sudden it stop working.Now today morning when i powered on my machine it is working fine.but got a new problem as now different views in the application are not pushing or poping.SO rather than wasting time to figure out the problem ,i rolled back my code to yesterday morning and saved a copy of faulty code.I will check the code for the problem later on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6: Keyboard does not show up in simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Following will fix the keyboard issue

*Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard* should solve this problem.

[image: ![Simulator->Hardware->Keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard]]

Comment: Thanks for the help,restarting the Mac fixed the problem ...@aiden

Comment: Ugh. Must have caught command shift k by accident and spent an hour trying to figure out why my keyboard wasn't appearing!  Thanks.

Comment: Note that it works only at the runtime moment when the keyboard is supposed to appear.

Answer (score 49):

Try this:

Goto:

```
iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard
```

And Uncheck

```
'Connect Hardware Keyboard'
```

Or simply do:  <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Keep Coding......... :)

Comment: I tried "Toggle Software Keyboard" and the keyboard appeared for me.

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this? :)

Answer (score 7):

This can also happen with Xcode 6/iOS 8 because of simulator settings:

[Xcode 6: Keyboard does not show up in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/swift-xcode-6-keyboard-not-showing-up-in-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure you aren't messing with `yourTextField.inputView`

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem but only on 5s simulator.  And, I tried to go to simulator->reset content and settings.  That actually solved the problem.

Comment: I'm glad to have found this suggestion but I'm not thrilled that I spent my night on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

in this regard check two things

1-`userInteractionEnabled=true`

2- `textFielfd.editable = YES;`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: NO ,As user Interaction is Enabled and white space is poping instead of keyboard

Comment: NO help with the second option

Answer (score 2):

check if at some point you're doing something like

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

or maybe you're assigning the first responder to some other control.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check if the outlet is mapped and the delegate set to the controller ? Also check if the controller has `<UITextFieldDelegate>` set. 
Send screen shot of the file inspector, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Add `[textField canBecomeFirstresponder];`

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem but on the actual device.
I talked to apple developer technical support (Apple DTS) and they told me that it's a swift compiler or Xcode bug.
I did a little workaround. Don't think that It's a best solution until apple solves this problem but it works without any problem now.

Just override the UITextField class:

```
class PBTextField : UITextField {

var keyboardShowDate = NSDate()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.initialisation()
}

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.initialisation()
}

func initialisation()
{
    self.addTarget(self, action: "editingDidBegin:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
    self.addTarget(self, action: "editingDidEnd:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
}

// MARK: Delegates

func editingDidBegin(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.keyboardShowDate = NSDate()
}

func editingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject)
{
    if(fabs(self.keyboardShowDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) <= 0.5)
    {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        dispatch_after(0.1, block: { () -> Void in
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
    }
}

}
```

dispatch methods:

```
typealias dispatch_cancelable_block_t = ((cancel: Bool) -> Void)

func dispatch_async(block: dispatch_block_t, background: Bool = true) -> dispatch_cancelable_block_t?
{
return dispatch_after(0, block: block, background: background)
}

func dispatch_after(delay: NSTimeInterval = 0, block: dispatch_block_t, background: Bool = false) -> dispatch_cancelable_block_t?
{
var cancelableBlock : dispatch_cancelable_block_t?

let delayBlock : dispatch_cancelable_block_t = { (cancel) -> Void in
    if(cancel == false)
    {
        if(background)
        {
            block()
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
        }
    }

    cancelableBlock = nil
};

cancelableBlock = delayBlock

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    if let cb = cancelableBlock
    {
        cb(cancel: false)
    }
})

return cancelableBlock
}

func cancel_block(block: dispatch_cancelable_block_t)
{
    block(cancel: true)
}
```

Hope this will help to someone.
If you got better solution, please let me know in comments.
Thanks
Giorgi